# Display a DocumentFragment in Vue

Tags: vue.js, documentfragment

I am using a library (prosemirror) that gives me a DocumentFragment out of json I get from the database. Now I want to display it in my component. How? Two hours of googling gave me nothing.

```
  resolveContent: function () {
    let contentNode = schema.nodeFromJSON(content)
    let fragment = DOMSerializer.fromSchema(schema).serializeFragment(contentNode.content)
    return fragment
  }
```

Using this in my component like

```
  p(v-html="resolveContent()")
```

or

```
  p {{resolveContent()}}
```

Prints

```
  [object DocumentFragment]
```

Answer (score 2):

To handle `DocumentFragment` within Vue.js, you will need to wait until Vue's `mounted` hook fires. I would create a wrapper component which "renders" simply an empty `<div/>`. Then, hook in to `mounted` and insert the fragment using standard DOM commands (eg. [Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild))

```js
const FragmentBootstrapper = Vue.extend({
  mounted() {
    const fragment = resolveContent()

    this.$el.appendChild(fragment)
  },
  render(h) {
    return h("div") // becomes `this.$el`
  }
}
```

This may feel weird at first, but it makes the most sense when you consider that Vue is a rendering layer *abstraction*. Thus, during its own rendering hook, it expects to only deal with its own VDOM. It provides the `mounted` hook in order to support various use-cases, namely this one.